# How to select first element that has content in JavaScript or CSS

Tags: javascript, css

Can anyone help me to select the first element that has content i.e. i want to select
the `</p>` element with the textContent  ***'Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet'***
which is the first `</p>` element with content.

**Code**

```
<div class="container">

  <p class="empty-para"><p>
  <p class="empty-para-ii"><p>
  <p> Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<p>
  <p> The quich brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.<p>

<div>
```

I need this answer to style the first `</p>` element(with content) with border

Comment: Hey, thanks for the question. What have you tried so far? Have you looked at [`Element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, CSS selector can be used to select all the non-empty children. And then simply use the zeroth element.

```js
let nonEmptyChildren = document.querySelectorAll('.container > p:not(:empty)');
if (nonEmptyChildren.length) {
    nonEmptyChildren[0].style.color = 'green'; // do whatever you want to the zeroth element.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution using Javascript

```js
const container = document.querySelector("div.container"); // Get the parent element
const elements = Array.from(container.children); // Transform to an array all container child elements
const element = elements.find((element) => element.textContent); // Find the first element with content

console.log(element);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="empty-para"></p>
  <p></p>
  <p class="empty-para-ii"></p>
  <p></p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p>
  <p></p>
  <p>The quich brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

See

- [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
const ptags = document.querySelectorAll('p');   // select all p tag elements
  ptags.forEach((item) => {
    if(item.text) {. //check if they have any text
        // do something with item
    }
  });
```

Comment: Hi Tushar, I am thanking you for your answer, but actually the thing i need is to select the first  `<p>`  element with content

Comment: When get to the `p` tag with content `The quich brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.` the condition will be fulfilled too

Answer (score 0):

first of all close your p tags like this :

```
<p> some content </p>
```

and i think you want this :

```
var tags = document.querySelectorAll('p');
var firstP = [] ;
tags.forEach(function(item){
 if(firstP.length > 0){
  return
 } 
 if(item.textContent){
  firstP.push(item);
  item.style.border = '1px solid red'
 } 
})
```